# Number of Comparisons Binary Insertion Sort and the Ceiling Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found that the number of comparisons for binary insertion sort is:

**First Pass**: 1 comparison as we compare the first two elements. 
**Second Pass**: 2 comparisonss as we compare the third elements with the first two elements.
**$k^{th}$ Pass**: $\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil$ comparisonss.

**Question**: Why the ceil function was used here instead of the floor function? I saw this is the case for a lot log-based algorithms, where the ceiling function is used to estimate operation numbers instead of floor functions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. $\lceil \log_2 n\rceil$ is the correct exact count, assuming that with $k$ comparisons you can binary search an array of size *at most* $2^k$. For example, $\log_25$ is between 2 and 3, but with 2 comparisons we can only binary search an array of size $2^2=4$, so we need $\lceil \log_25\rceil=3$ comparisons to binary search a 5-element array.
2. If the goal is to prove an upper bound on an algorithm's runtime, then rounding down would be unsound, but rounding up is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please rephrase "(because we want to be certain that the exact number of steps is less than the function of n we produce)"? Since it's an upper bound, should it be larger than number of steps function produce?

Comment: Ah yeah, I meant that the actual number of steps must be less than our estimate, because we're trying to show that the number of steps is "small". I'll rephrase to clarify.